# Open Source for barcode reader

Tags: iphone, barcode-scanner

I am developing a barcode reader application and wants to upload it for free on appstore.
So I need a free OPEN SOURCE that helps in barcode reading through images sent from iPhone(including 3G).

I have seen several threads but the reference provided by them are all paid APIs.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hi bro i downloaded this API but when i try to run it gives me this type of error    No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv6, VALID_ARCHS=i386 ppc ppc64 ppc7400 ppc970 x86_64).

Could you let me know how to get rid of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at the iphone port of zxing
http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/#svn/trunk/iphone

Comment: I have seen it but I need for the 3g iPhones too... and zxing is for 3gs onwards.

Comment: There aren't any open source projects that have better support than ZXing. The problem is 3g iPhones don't have autofocus, so they are very bad at scanning. You have to pay for QuickMark or RedLaser to get 3g scanning, and even then it doesn't work that well.

Comment: Thanks @Kenny.Any alternate for 3g except the paid ones?

Comment: I had a working app for QR working on my 3GS within 15 minutes using the zxing code. I did not have much luck with barcodes, though. They might be tougher to parse.

Comment: ZXing will work on a 3G as long as it is running iOS4. Even with fixed focus, it does a pretty good job of decoding QR codes. I hear barcodes are harder (but they're not my focus, so to speak).

Answer (score 3):

I have been using http://zbar.sourceforge.net/ (iphone link:http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/index.html) and it works very, very well.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://zxing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk) is the download link Which doesnt have a version for iPhone. It could not find the CoreVideo framework and will give an error. Core Video framework is not available on iPhones prior to 3GS. It has the video recording functionality that is not available in the earlier versions of the phone. So if you are trying to install it on a 3G phone, it will give you an error.
 And as told in the previous comments I havent seen anything better than zxing....

Comment: This is wrong. There are AVFoundation APIs that came out in iOS4 that are needed but iOS4 runs on a 3G. You can't install it on a phone running iOS3 which does preclude 2s, though.

Comment: @smparkes: That works fine on 3GS and as u told AVFoundation Api came out in iOS4 then it mustnt work woth 3GS too right?

Comment: iOS4 and the new AVFoundation APIs work on 3G, 3GS, and 4. The 3 doesn't support video recording but it does implement the screen capture APIs.

Comment: You just download the above code(from the link) and you will get to know that if you are trying to install it in 3G It will give you an error of core video framework...